# problems with ProgressDialog,RunOnUiThread and ListAdapter

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments

Ok i've written this android program that has 3 tabs(MEALS,DRINKS AND DESSERT) each in its own activity with a fragment.The problem i'm having now is with retrieving the list from a mysql database and displaying this list in each tab.I'de already ran and executed a custom code which displays a list of items retrieved from a mysql database in a single list,which worked fine.Now bringing this code to my program gives me 3 errors
1)

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MealsFragment.this); which says        
ProgressDialog(android.context,Context) in progressDialog cannot be applied to          
com.example.tab.tablayout.MealsFragment
```

2)
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() which says "cannot resolve method runonuithread "

3)is all about the list adapter.

The initial code used OnCreate,but my fragment uses oncreateView.I dont know if thats the issue.

Here is the code for the MealsFragment.java

```
package com.example.tabs.tablayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by GIGABYTE on 5/21/2014.
 */
public class MealsFragment extends ListFragment {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mealsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_meals = "http://10.180.79.73/dbase_connect/get_all_meals.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MEALS = "meals";
    private static final String TAG_MID = "mid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray meals = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meals, container, false);



        // Hashmap for ListView
        mealsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading meals in Background Thread
        new LoadAllMeals().execute();


        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        return rootView;
    }


    /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         * */
       class LoadAllMeals extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MealsFragment.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Meals. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * getting All Meals from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_meals, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON response
                Log.d("All Meals: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // Meals found
                        // Getting Array of Meals
                        meals = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MEALS);

                        // looping through All meals
                        for (int i = 0; i < meals.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = meals.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_MID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_MID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            mealsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } /*else {
                        // no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                NewProductActivity.class);
                        // Closing all previous activities
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    */
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all meals
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MealsFragment.this, mealsList,
                                R.layout.meals_list_item, new String[] {TAG_MID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.mid, R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);


                    }
                });

            }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The first parameter of the ProgressDialog constructor must be a context. Use

```
new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

2) You could use `getActivity().runOnUiThread(...)`. However, that's not necessary in this context. The `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` method is already running in the UI thread. Just move the Runnable code into the body of the `onPostExecute()` method.

3) Same as 1, first parameter must be a context. Use `new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), ...)`.

Comment: I've Used getActivity().runOnUiThread(...) and it seems to have solved the problem.But im still stuck with the other two which are  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MealsFragment.this); which says        
ProgressDialog(android.context,Context) in progressDialog cannot be applied to  com.example.tab.tablayout.MealsFragment     and the last code ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter().Please What can i do?

Comment: @Rosius edited the answer with the other two issues.

Comment: JESSSUSS CHRIST!!!! Ur Gooooood.Thanks Alot @Matiash..I really appreciate all the help.Thank You....Peace